# how edge ngram token filter differs from ngram token filter?

Tags: elasticsearch, token, analyzer

As I am new to elastic search, I am not able to identify difference between *ngram token filter* and
*edge ngram token filter*.

How these two differ from each other in
processing tokens?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) is pretty clear on this:

> This tokenizer is very similar to nGram but only keeps n-grams which start at the beginning of a token.

And the best example for `nGram` tokenizer again comes from the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html):

```
curl 'localhost:9200/test/_analyze?pretty=1&analyzer=my_ngram_analyzer' -d 'FC Schalke 04'


    # FC, Sc, Sch, ch, cha, ha, hal, al, alk, lk, lke, ke, 04
```

With this tokenizer definition:

```
                    "type" : "nGram",
                    "min_gram" : "2",
                    "max_gram" : "3",
                    "token_chars": [ "letter", "digit" ]
```

In short:

- the tokenizer, depending on the configuration, will create tokens. In this example: `FC`, `Schalke`, `04`.
- `nGram` generates groups of characters of minimum `min_gram` size and maximum `max_gram` size from an input text. Basically, the tokens are split into small chunks and each chunk is anchored on a character (it doesn't matter where this character is, all of them will create chunks).
- `edgeNGram` does the same but the chunks always start from the beginning of each token. Basically, the chunks are anchored at the beginning of the tokens.

For the same text as above, an `edgeNGram` generates this: `FC, Sc, Sch, Scha, Schal, 04`. Every "word" in the text is considered and for every "word" the first character is the starting point (`F` from `FC`, `S` from `Schalke` and `0` from `04`).

Comment: stefen..i made some changes to question please consider updated  one.

Comment: I don't understand the updated question. What is not clear?

Comment: My explanation stands even for `token filters`.

Answer (score 10):

`ngram` moves the cursor while breaking the text:

```
Text: Red Wine

Options:
    ngram_min: 2
    ngram_max: 3

Result: Re, Red, ed, Wi, Win, in, ine, ne
```

As you see here, the cursor moves `ngram_min` times to the next fragment until it reaches the `ngram_max`.

---

`ngram_edge` does the exact same thing as `ngram` but it doesn't move the cursor:

```
Text: Red Wine

Options:
    ngram_min: 2
    ngram_max: 3

Result: Re, Red
```

Why didn't it return `Win`? because the cursor doesn't move, it'll always start from the position zero, moves `ngram_min` times and backs to the same position (which is always zero).

---

Think of `ngram_edge` as if it was a `substring` function in other programming languages such as JavaScript:

```js
// ngram
let str = "Red Wine";
console.log(str.substring(0, 2)); // Re
console.log(str.substring(0, 3)); // Red
console.log(str.substring(1, 3)); // ed, start from position 1
// ...

// ngram_edge
// notice that the position is always zero
console.log(str.substring(0, 2)); // Re
console.log(str.substring(0, 3)); // Red
```

---

Try it out by yourself using Kibana:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_ngram_tokenizer" : {
          "type" : "ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 3,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        },
        "my_edge_ngram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 3
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST my_index/_analyze
{
  "tokenizer": "my_ngram_tokenizer",
  "text": "Red Wine"
}

POST my_index/_analyze
{
  "tokenizer": "my_edge_ngram_tokenizer", 
  "text": "Red Wine"
}
```

Comment: This is the best explanation i've ever seen thanks!